# How much data is available on the Internet?

Tags: data-request, internet

I saw these sentences [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_of_Things):

> Nearly all of the roughly 50 petabytes (a petabyte is 1,024 terabytes) of data available on the Internet were first captured and created by human beings—by typing, pressing a record button, taking a digital picture or scanning a bar code.

Is that correct?
If we suppose that just a DVD movie is at least 4.7 GB, I think it should much more than 50 petabyte.

Comment: But is a DVD movie 'data'?  That gets you into all sorts of other philosophical questions.  You also get issues with duplication -- if we assume that DVD is 'data', and there are 102,400 copies of it ... is it 4.7GB of data, or 470TB of data?  I'd argue it's only  4.7GB (or 0, if it's not considered to be data)

Comment: @Joe It seems that the author considered it as data when he says "pressing a record button". Sorry if my last sentence was confusing. I didn't say just copies of a single movie is over 50 petabyte. I said all of the movies on the internet without duplication are over 50 petabyte.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Measurement Lab](http://www.measurementlab.net).

One estimate I've heard is that researchers at the Measurement Lab (M-Lab) publish over 750Tb of data under a CCZero licence.